# How to submit a computer science paper to arXiv when I am a physicist?

Tags: paper-submission, arxiv

I am member of the Physics Department at my uni. I did the arXiv registration and automatically was allowed to submit papers in maths and physics. However I am interested in submitting a pre-print work in computational linguistics (mixed with acoustics). I found the right place in arXiv to do this: https://arxiv.org/list/cs.CL/new. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to sumbit papers to computer science -> computational linguistics. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is somewhat hidden. Here's where you find that:

Login to the arXiv, go to "My Account". Below the info-box with your information there is the link "Change User Information". There you'll find boxes for the different groups to tick.